# How to populate environment variables in Jenkinsfile from a json file

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, devops, cicd

I don't know how to populate the environment variables in the Jenkinsfile from a json file. And also I need to make agent_label as a variable

```
pipeline {
    agent {
      label '{$AGENT_LABEL}'
    }
    tools {
      maven 'Maven_3.8.6'
    }
 stage('Deploy on AWS through Code Deploy') {
        when {
          branch "test"
        }
        steps {
          step([$class: 'AWSCodeDeployPublisher', applicationName: '{$ENV.APPLICATION_NAME}', deploymentGroupAppspec: false, deploymentGroupName: '{$ENV.DEPLOYMENT_GROUP}', deploymentMethod: 'deploy',deploymentConfig: 'CodeDeployDefault.OneAtATime',externalId: 'xxxxxxx', excludes: '', iamRoleArn: 'arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxx:role/allow_old_staging_codedeploy', includes: '**', proxyHost: '', proxyPort: 0, region: 'region', s3bucket: 'deploy-bucket', s3prefix: 'live-utility', subdirectory: '', versionFileName: '', waitForCompletion: true])
        }
      }
```

I don't Know how to implement this. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

The beow variables should be called from the json file.

{$AGENT_LABEL}

{$ENV.APPLICATION_NAME}

{$ENV.DEPLOYMENT_GROUP}

Comment: https://community.jenkins.io/t/extracting-a-value-from-a-json-file-and-storing-it-in-an-environment-variable/1317